# Changing a Visual Studio C# project from x86 to Any CPU

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I am working on some C# projects with Visual Studio 2005, and I am trying to change the platform target from x86 to Any CPU. I already went through all the dependencies that I know about and made sure that they were also built for Any CPU using the corflags tool.

When I change the platform target in Visual Studio 2005 it seems like it saves the change, but then when I build the project it still uses x86 anyway. The next time I open the project the platform target has been reset to x86.

This only happens for a couple of the projects in the solution, does this mean that there are other 32-bit dependencies somewhere?

I can manually run the C# compiler on the command line with `/platform:anycpu` and I don't get an error, but I'm not sure that is the right thing to do and I'd like to be able to build within Visual Studio.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you changed the platform target in all configurations (i.e. both in Debug and Release configuration)?

Comment: I don't think VS cares about the dependencies.  I've been able to build AnyCPU projects that had 32-bit dependencies -- that crash promptly (and appropriately) when the DLL's tried to load.  Go with divo's suggestion.

Comment: I did change the platform target in all configurations, and it still runs the compiler with /platform:x86 and doesn't save the change in the project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure you've changed both the **Configuration Platform** and the **Platform Target** to `Any CPU`. If all else fails you can open up the `.csproj` and manually change the references. Right click on the Project, goto Unload Project. Then right click and goto `Edit MyProject.csproj`. The properties for the project may still include the default Platform as x86:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
```

Also consider the case where the Solution still has the x86 configuration in Configuration Manager. I've found for some complex Solutions with multiple projects that have different configurations I have to spend a lot of time in Configuration Manager getting everything straight.

Comment: I had changed both the Configuration Platform and Platform Target, and it still wouldn't save the change. I was able to edit the .csproj file and do it that way, so I think this is what I was looking for at this point. Whether or not it actually runs is another story. I still get the feeling that this might have to do with dependencies that I can't see being targeted for other platforms, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Came across this trying to resolve the same issue... I eventually discovered that even if a project is set to debug for, say, Debug/Any CPU in the solution configuration for Debug/Any CPU, the project's properties page, 'build' tab, lets you pick a target platform for 'Debug/Any CPU'.  In my case, 'Debug/Any CPU' targeted x86 explicitly, and so when I compiled the project for Debug/Any CPU, the resulting DLL was explicitly compiled for x86... which caused Invalid Format errors when loaded in an x64 environment.  And there was much 'wtf?' to be had.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about the Configuration Manager settings... there are two places to potentially mis-specify the configuration.  The solution manager lets you set the project to 'Release/x64' for the 'Debug/Any CPU' configuration... the project properties' build tab lets you say 'Release/x64' targets the x86 platform.  Confused yet?

Comment: I know this is a little old, but having just fixed a similar issue.. I believe that the wtf issues @JamesB and others is having  had is created when you attempt to change the platform target to X but it doesn't exist, so you create X but select "based on Y". Therefore you have a platform called X that has the properties of Y. You therefore need to amend the sln file explicitly in a text editor so you don;t get a mix like this: Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU .

Comment: Unloading the project and editing the .csproj worked just fine for me. And the changes reflected fine in visual studio. I deployed/published with no issues. Great solution.